# Unexpected Token ) on Ionic 3 Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic3

I sometimes got this error when run my application on android emulator.
When I run my application on my device, there is no error like that but there is something strange with my notification bar on my device, notification bar become black. Have someone experienced it? May I have some suggestions?
Thank you.

[Unexpected Token )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E4qA.png)

Comment: Okay I found the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to make my notification bar become light.

```
initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
    // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
    this.splashScreen.hide();
  });
}
```